# bpy.ops.object.scale_clear(clear_delta=false) (the alt-s command in 3d view) lowers ram usage?

Tags: python, scripting, scale, memory-management

One of my projects has a script that creates thousands of objects every time it runs and even though it deleted the old objects there's still a ram build-up over time. For example, just now it hit 24gb (out of my 32). I found a trick a while back where if I run the alt-s command repeatedly eventually the program will freeze for a minute then drop my ram. It dropped from 24 to 6 gb with no apparent consequences since I create objects by dimension not scale. Does anyone know why this is the case? Is there a better way to delete objects than just the delete() method?